# What displacement means in electric displacement and displacement current?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am wondering about the meaning of the word "displacement" in the following physics terms: electric displacement and displacement current. It seems to me that they have nothing to do with position.

Comment: Isn't this a science question rather than a language question?

Comment: I've just looked up "electric displacement" and it seems to me that Maxwell coined the term  because he was describing electric charges which spread out across the surface of conductors rather than passing through them so there is an element of physical displacement involved. The charge is 'displaced' or diverted from the path from anode to cathode. The fact that it is now a technical term does not invalidate this etymology.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on the Electrical Engineering site.

Comment: As newcomer to the site, do not be discouraged by the unexplained and negative downvote of your question. It is true that, according to the site guidelines, a good question shows evidence of personal research. Nevertheless, we do not usually vote down a newcomer for such a small thing. We rather aim to encourage you. It is also a possibility that the downvote was the result of a sometimes encountered, and quite blinkered, viewpoint that science is somehow divorced from language. This of course is nonsense. There may be other reasons but the anonymous downvoter makes no effort to explain them

Comment: The site guidelines clearly include "Word choice and usage" as components of suitable questions. The choice of "displacement" and its usage in the context of the question merit answers, not closure.

Answer (score 1):

This is a valid language question based on the usage of words to describe a physical phenomenon.

There is a positional aspect to displacement. For example:

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/displacement)
> *displacement*: the difference between the initial position of something (such as a body or geometric figure) and any later position.

The electric displacement is a measure of the intensity of the electric field between two or more electric charges (positive and negative) that are *displaced* from each other.

If this intensity varies with time for some reason, the rate of change of the displacement is known as the displacement current. For a simple example, the charges may be moving together or apart (moving charges constitute a current), changing the field intensity and creating a *displacement current* related to the movement of the charges.

The terms therefore relate to position. The first to displacement of position when charges are separated from their natural state of being attracted together. The second to changes in position of the displaced charges.

Comment: See my comments on the question. Mute downvoters help nobody.

Comment: Displacement relates to a loss of position (as place)?

Comment: @G.Rem In a sense, yes. Cambridge (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/displacement), for example, has displacement = "when people are forced to leave the place where they normally live". In being displaced from one position to another they lose their place at the first position.